# Foreach in codeigniter not working properly

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

The concept of my project is fetching price based on day from database.I have successfully get data from database,but the problem is i couldn't fetch the price amount for the corresponding day,here i am using dynamic days i don't know how to fetch it.

```
$day1 = $date->format('l')."\n";
$this->db->select($day1);
$this->db->where('filename',$data['roomname']);
$query = $this->db->get('rooms'); 
$bb = $query->result();
print_r($bb);
foreach($bb as $row)
 $price =  $price + $row->$day1;
```

The error,

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$Tuesday

Filename: controllers/home.php

Line Number: 332
```

[My table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTNV5.png)

Hope someone can point me the solutions.
Thanks.

Comment: @NeilMasson this is the line  `$price =  $price + $row->$day1;`

Comment: What is the value of `$day1`???

Comment: can you show the output of `print_r($bb);`

Comment: see my updated question@Saty

Comment: print_r($row); print_r($day1); show them please

Comment: On this $query->result(); try $query->result_array();

Answer (score 0):

May be your $day is a string with space so Change your code according to this and try

```
  $bb = $query->result();
  $day1 = str_replace(' ', '', $day1); 
  foreach($bb as $row)
     $price =  $price + $row->$day1;
```

Or,

```
  $bb = $query->result_array();
  $day1 = str_replace(' ', '', $day1); 
  foreach($bb as $row)
     $price =  $price + $row[$day1];
```

Or as a row:

```
  $bb = $query->row();
  $day1 = str_replace(' ', '', $day1);
     $price =  $price + $bb->$day1;
```

I hope it works

Comment: Oops !,

Can you show your price and days relation, that means your table structure.

Comment: I uploaded the database structure @Kabir Hossain.

Comment: print_r($day1) and print_r($bb) and give me as comment.

Comment: For print_r($bb) ` Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [Tuesday] => 3045 ) )`

Comment: For print_r($day1) `Tuesday`@Kabir Hossain

Comment: try using $bb = $query->result_array();
  foreach($bb as $row)
     $price =  $price + $row[$day1];

Comment: I used the above code.but i get Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array @Kabir Hossain

Comment: I have a value of date,using this date i get day,So days are dynamic.I can't use static value @Kabir Hossain

Comment: Oops,there is one row so change this,$bb = $query->row();
 $price =  $price + $bb->$day1;

Comment: Thanks for the help.I got the answer after changing the code like `$bb = $query->row();foreach($bb as $row) $price = $price + $bb->$day1;`

Answer (score 0):

please remove the "\n" from your code by

**change this:**

```
$day1 = $date->format('l')."\n";
```

**To:**

```
$day1 = $date->format('l');
```

Answer (score -1):

CodeIgniter returns result rows as objects, not arrays.

> result() : This function returns the query result as an array of
>   objects, or an empty array on failure.

You'll have to access the fields using the following notation:

```
foreach($bb as $row)
    $price =  $price + $row->day1;
```

if you really want an array instead you can use:

```
$bb = $query->result_array();
```

which would return the same information as an associative array

Then you can access it as:

```
foreach($bb as $row)
    $price =  $price + $row[$day1];
```